# Sub query not in issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data here is chart and apptdate (chart is patient number).
I want to know which patients have not had an appt. since  20170301

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE apptdate not in (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
    WHERE APPTDATE > '20170301'
)
```

but this query is rejected

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Can we assume that chart (Aka patient id) can have more than one record in DDB_APPT_BASE?

Comment: yes, you could have one appt or hundreds

Answer (score 2):

If a `chart` is a "patient", then you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
GROUP BY chart
HAVING MAX(apptdate) < '20170301';
```

If you wanted, you could do this using `NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN`, although I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS`) with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dab.chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] dab
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE]  dab2
                  WHERE dab2.chart = dab.chart AND dab2.APPTDATE > '20170301'
                 );
```

But I think the first approach is easier.

Comment: I wonder which would perform better. With the first query, I would think the DB needs to find all the records for the patient to get the max, but with the second query it can stop as soon as it finds any matching record. Of course, with any DB perf question, the answer is: try it.

Comment: @aquinas . . . It is worth trying to see which is better.  The `select distinct` should be about expensive as the `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

With the 'NOT IN' operator only 1 field can be returned in the subquery.

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE apptdate not in (
    SELECT apptdate
    FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
    WHERE APPTDATE > '20170301'
)
```

However, why don't you just do:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE APPTDATE <= '20170301'
```

Comment: Indeed for the alternate version!

Comment: It's `NOT in ()`, so he should invert the comparison: `APPTDATE <= '20170301'`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks Joel, you are right. Edited with the correction.

Comment: Why would an answer where both queries are wrong be upvoted?

Comment: Just asked the OP, but I think it's HIGHLY likely that there is more than one row per "chart"

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not saying you are wrong, but what error do you see?

Comment: @YellowBedwetter . . . The first returns all patients who have an appointment earlier than 2017-03-01 (even those with later appointments).  The second . . . well, it returns the same thing.  In both cases, patients with more recent appointments are returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed, I got tunnel vision on the query and error provided and didn't even realize what he actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT chart
        FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] where chart not in  (SELECT chart
         FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] where APPTDATE > '20170301')
```

Comment: It's `NOT in ()`, so he should invert the comparison: `APPTDATE <= '20170301'`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] where APPTDATE not in  
(SELECT app.APPTDATE FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as app
WHERE app.APPTDATE > '20170301')
```

and why can't you use this:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] as app 
WHERE app.APPTDATE <= '20170301'
```

Answer (score 0):

This nested query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE APPTDATE > '20170301'
```

has `*` as the `SELECT` list, which may include many items. The error message is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list

So pick one specific column... specifically, you want `APPTDATE`:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE apptdate not in (
    SELECT APPTDATE
    FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
    WHERE APPTDATE > '20170301'
)
```

Additionally, you can logically reduce that query down to just this:

```
SELECT chart
FROM [Dentrix].[dbo].[DDB_APPT_BASE] 
WHERE APPTDATE <=  '20170301'
```